# jQuery - calculations of values in the multiple inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-calculation

I have basic order form, i would like to sum values form all inputs . But when I add items program adds the values to a string insted summarizing them (totalUnits).

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/97tnrepg/48/

and the part of a code to bring your attention to a right place

```
function CalculateTotal(){
var total = 0;
for(i = 0; i< orders.length; i++){
    total = total + orders[i].packTotal;
}
console.log(total);
console.log(totalUnits);

if(total > 0){
    var counter = 0;  
    $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() != 0) counter++;
    });

    var totalUnits = 0; 
    $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        packUnit = $(this).val();
        totalUnits = totalUnits + packUnit;
        });

    $("#order_total").html('Ordered Products:' + counter + '<br>' + 'Total Items:' + totalUnits + '<br>' + 'Order Subtotal: ' + total);
    $("#order_total").show();
    $('.submitorder').show();
}
if(total == 0){
    $("#order_total").html('Your shopping basket is empty');
    $("#order_total").show();
    $('.submitorder').hide();
}
}
```

Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to convert strings into integers

---

Use `parseInt` when you get inputs values :

```
var packPrice = parseInt($('#pack' + curId + '-price').val());
var packUnit = parseInt($(this).val());
```

And in your `calculateTotal()` function also :

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    packUnit = parseInt($(this).val());
    totalUnits = totalUnits + packUnit;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsr0ugqn/)

Comment: Thank you @EdenSource. Great lesson for me as newbe to jQuery/JS